# archivedData(withRootObject:)' was deprecated in iOS 12.0 - Swift 5 and Flutter

Tags: swift, flutter

I have a project which was written (iOS part) with Swift 4. I update it to 5 but now I have this warnings. I've tried to fix it as it's suggest but I get different error each time. Could you help me with it?

Code

```
func saveData(data: BloodData) {
    if let defaults = getUserDefaults() {
      BloodData.registerClassName()
      let encodedData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: data)
      defaults.set(encodedData, forKey: dataKey)
      defaults.synchronize()
    }
  }
```

Warning

```
archivedData(withRootObject:)' was deprecated in iOS 12.0: Use +archivedDataWithRootObject:requiringSecureCoding:error: instead
```

Code

```
 func getData() -> BloodData? {
    BloodData.registerClassName()
    if let defaults = getUserDefaults(), let data = defaults.data(forKey: dataKey), let decodedData = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? BloodData {
      return computeData(data: decodedData)
    }
    return nil
  }
```

Warning

```
'unarchiveObject(with:)' was deprecated in iOS 12.0: Use +unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error: instead
```

Here's a computeData func:

```
private func computeData(data: BloodData) -> BloodData? {
    let today = Date()
    
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    let date1 = calendar.date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 00, second: 00, of: calendar.startOfDay(for: data.readingDate))!
    
    let date2 = calendar.date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 00, second: 00, of: calendar.startOfDay(for: today))!

    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: date1, to: date2)
    let dayDiff = components.day ?? 0
    
    let newBloodData = BloodData(
      whiteCells: data.whiteCells - dayDiff,
      fullBlood: data.fullBlood - dayDiff,
      platelet: data.platelet - dayDiff,
      redCells1: data.redCells1 - dayDiff,
      redCells2: data.redCells2 - dayDiff,
      bloodPlasma: data.bloodPlasma - dayDiff,
      readingDate: date2
    )
    
    return newBloodData
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When coding in Swift most of the time the errors are not very helpful.
The first one is pretty self explanatory, except that the suggested method might throw an error. You can remove the throw keyword and ignore the error with try? if you would like to but it is better to catch and handle the errors:

```
func save(blood: BloodData, forKey defaultName: String = "BloodDataKey") {  // or forKey defaultName: String = dataKey
    guard let data = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: blood, requiringSecureCoding: false) else { return }
    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: defaultName)
}
```

The second error doesn't help at all. You can use NSKeyedUnarchiver's method unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData and it throws as well:

```
func getBlood(forKey defaultName: String = "BloodDataKey") -> BloodData? {  // or forKey defaultName: String = dataKey
    guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: defaultName) else { return nil }
    guard let bloodData = (try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data)) as? BloodData else { return nil }
    return computeData(data: bloodData)
}
```

Comment: I've made an edit in main post. (computeData part added)

Comment: @P-J you just need to unwrap the resulting BloodData instead of returning it using guard and use computeData to return your BloodData manipulating it

Comment: Could you guide me somehow? I didn't wrote that iOS part and I'm little bit confused